# Encrypt iOS app ipa file

Tags: iphone

I hope to encrypt the ipa file of a freeware for jailbreak users so that others cannot view the project details.

Is there any tool to do this?

Welcome any comment

Comment: Well, actually you can encrypt any file you can get your hands on -- there are plenty of public domain encryption packages.  You just can't do anything with it once it's encrypted.

Comment: Is the app supposed to be on the App Store or do you want to distribute it only to jailbreakers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my knowledge, **you CANNOT do anything** like that ! And apple probably won't allow your app to go on the AppStore in the first place.

The way the ipa file is generated (as of now), **jailbreaking does not allow** the hacker to view the classes or the underlying code/algorithm used ( I think he can view the images used via iExplorer or may a simple ssh would suffice). Encrypting that further is not really a great solution considering you want the app to be uploaded on the AppStore.

All developers strictly abide by Apple's rules, and its their domain. The only thing developers will have to worried about is *Paid* apps being available for *free* on the web..  With respect to that,  may be we can expect a solution from Apple to prevent *Piracy* later this year (Hopefully)