# How to protect App binary and class dump in an iPhone app?

Tags: ios, cordova, encryption, ipa

I have an iPhone app made using Cordova (Hybrid).

Now in the InfoSec review of the app in my company, there is a concern on this one point - "The app binary is not encrypted and class dump can be directly obtained"

Now what I have studied on the net and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099184/encrypt-ios-app-ipa-file), IPAs should not be encrypted; And Apple takes care of encryption and signing when the app is published to the app store.

Is the above point i.e. "The app binary is not encrypted and class dump can be directly obtained" invalid?

What can I do to protect the app at the developer level? Since its a Hybrid app, I have already uglified the components.

Comment: App binaries are signed by Apple for distribution but not encrypted. What is the concern over obtaining a class dump?

Comment: i dont know their concern :(

Comment: Maybe you can ask them to explain their concern. Code cannot be modified without invalidating Apple's signature. Code can be decompiled but there is little you can do about that on any platform apart from obfuscation